# Integrate Gerrit with Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gerrit, integrate

Do you have any tips or tutorials how to integrate **Gerrit** with **Gitlab** - **Gerrit** should be as code review for **Gitlab** repo?

Answer (score 3):

yes it can be integrated easily, install gitlab and gerrit.

```
1. create your repository on gitlab.
2. git clone --mirror <gitlab repo url>
3. create project on gerrit.
4. git push --mirror <gerrit_project_url>
5. configure gerrit replication plugin, this will replicate your all the changes to gitlab.
```

NOTE : you can use gerrit oauth plugin to authenticate using gitlab and jenkins to verify build.

https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/replication/+doc/master/src/main/resources/Documentation/config.md